# Counting the number of polynomials of degree $n$ with integer coefficients.

Tags: real-analysis

I was working through Understanding Analysis by Abbott and one of the problems asked to prove that the set of all algebraic numbers is countable. We know a number $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is algebraic if there exist integers $a_0, \dots , a_n \in \mathbb{Z}$, not all 0, such that

$$
a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+ \cdots + a_1x + a_0 = 0.
$$

So, for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, if we let $A_n$ be the set of algebraic numbers obtained as roots of polynomials with integer coefficients that have degree $n$ we can write this set as a union of finite sets as follows. For each $m \in \mathbb{N}$ consider the set

$$
B_m=\left\{x : \sum_{i=0}^n{a_ix^i}=0, \sum_{i=0}^n{|a_i|}=m, |a_n| \geq 1 \right\}. 
$$

Since each polynomial has a finite number of roots, if we can show that the number of polynomials satisfying the constraints in the set $B_m$ is finite then we know that $B_m$ itself is finite. With $B_m$ being finite we then have $A_n = \cup_{m=1}^\infty{B_m}$. We show that $B_m$ is finite as follows.

The set up of the problem is that we are given a polynomial of degree $n$

$$
a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1x+a_0
$$

where $a_n, \dots, a_0 \in \mathbb{Z}$, and we want to count the total number of polynomials such that

$$
|a_n|+|a_{n-1}|+ \cdots + |a_1|+|a_0|=m.
$$

Since it's specified that our polynomial is of degree $n$, we know that all of our polynomials will contain an $n$th degree term in them, and so $|a_n| \geq 1$. To make things easy for us we will separately count the polynomials that have just 1 term in them, then 2 terms, then 3 terms, all the way up to $n+1$ terms. Before proceeding with this we take a quick detour. We will prove the following lemma.

> For $n \in \mathbb{N}$, given $b_1,b_2, \dots , b_n, m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $m \geq 2$, the sum $b_1+ \cdots + b_n = m$ can be formed in ${m-1}\choose{n-1}$ ways.

We prove this via induction. The case when $n=2$ is immediately obvious. If we know $b_1,b_2 \geq 1$ and $b_1+b_2=m$ then $b_1$ can take on any integer value from 1 to $m-1$ and in doing so this determines the value of $b_2$. Thus there are $m-1$ = ${m-1}\choose{1}$ arrangements of this sum. Now assume the statement holds true for $n=k-1$. Thus for any $b_1,b_2, \dots , b_{k-1}, m \in \mathbb{N}$ with $m \geq 2$,  $b_1+\cdots+b_{k-1}=m$ can be formed in ${m-1}\choose{k-2}$ different ways. We show it holds true for $n=k$.

Let $b_1,b_2, \dots , b_k, m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $m \geq 2$. If we fix $b_1=1$ our sum becomes $b_2+b_3+\cdots+b_k=m-1$, and we know that there are ${m-2}\choose{k-2}$ possible ways to form this sum via the inductive step. Similarly, if we fix $b_1=2$ our sum becomes $b_2+b_3+\cdots+b_k=m-3$ and again via the inductive step we know that there are ${m-3}\choose{k-2}$ possible ways to form this sum. Continuing this process we find that the total amount of ways to form this sum is

$$
{{m-2}\choose{k-2}}+{{m-3}\choose{k-2}}+ \cdots + {{m-(m-(k-2))}\choose{k-2}}.
$$

And now since we know that if $0 \leq k \leq n$ then $\sum_{j=0}^n{j \choose k} = {{n+1}\choose{k+1}}$, this sum becomes

$$
{{m-2}\choose{k-2}}+{{m-3}\choose{k-2}}+ \cdots + {{k-2}\choose{k-2}}={{m-1}\choose{k-1}}
$$

and our result follows via induction. Note that if $n > m$, the total number of ways the sum can be formed is 0 and the formula still holds.

Back to counting our polynomials. If the polynomial has $k$ terms where $1 \leq k \leq n+1$ we begin by choosing $k-1$ of the coefficients that will be included in our polynomial (because we know $a_n$ must be included), there are ${{n}\choose{k-1}}$ possible choices for the other coefficients aside from $a_n$. The absolute values of these coefficients must also sum up to $m$, and by our lemma above there are ${{m-1}\choose{k-1}}$ possible ways to make this sum. Lastly, since we are working with absolute values the sign of each coefficient can flip between positive and negative and so there are $2^k$ possibilities for choice of signs for all the coefficients. Thus there are

$$
{{n}\choose{k-1}}{{m-1}\choose{k-1}}2^k
$$

total polynomials of degree $n$ with $k$ terms who have integer coefficients that sum to $m$ in absolute value. Using this we have that the total number of polynomials of degree $n$ who have integer coefficients that sum to $m$ in absolute value is given by

$$
{{n}\choose{0}}{{m-1}\choose{0}}2^1+{{n}\choose{1}}{{m-1}\choose{1}}2^2+\cdots+{{n}\choose{k-1}}{{m-1}\choose{k-1}}2^k+\cdots+{{n}\choose{n}}{{m-1}\choose{n}}2^{n+1}.
$$

Since this is a finite number of polynomials, and each polynomial has a finite number of roots then each $B_m$ is a finite set and as stated before $A_n = \cup_{m=1}^\infty{B_m}$ is a countable union of finite sets and is thus countable. The algebraic numbers can then be represented as the countable union of countable sets $\cup_{n=1}^\infty{A_n}$, which is itself countable. So the algebraic numbers are countable.

Is this a valid proof? It seems like there should be an easier way to prove the lemma compared to the way that I did. Is there an intuition behind why the total possible ways to make that sum is ${m-1}\choose{n-1}$? Any comments and corrections are welcome as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof looks correct! To make a more simple proof I would define $B_m = \{x : \sum_{i = 0}^n a_ix^i = 0$ where $m = max \{|a_i|\}\}$.

I think this proof is a little easier since its a little easier to show that the number of polynomials satisfying the constraints in the set $B_m$ is finite. Let $j \in \mathbb{Z}$ be maximal such that $|a_j| = m$. Clearly $a_j = -m$ or $a_j = m$ so there are $2$ choices for $a_j$. Next there are $n + 1$ many possible choices for $j$. Now each of the $n - j$ terms before $j$ must in the set $\{-m + 1, -m+ 2, ... , -1, 0, 1,... , m - 2, m - 1\}$ i.e. there are $2m - 1$ many choices for each term of the $n - j$ terms preceding $a_j$. Similarly there are $2m + 1$ many choices for each term of the $j$ terms following $a_j$.

Finlay we see that the number of polynomials satisfying the constraints for $B_m =$ the number of choices for $j$ times the number of chooses for each term of the $n - j$ terms before $a_j$ times the $2$ choices for the value of $a_j$ times the number of choices for for the $j$ terms after $j$

$= n + 1 \times (2m - 1)^{n - j} \times 2 \times (2m + 1)^j$

After this the rest of the proof is the same as yours.

Comment: That’s another great way! I like this a lot better, thank you.